# Android Studio - Start an Activity with a parameter

Tags: android

I am new with Android Studio. I am working on following code but it is not working, kindly help me out.

I am trying to send an int value but emulator stopped working every time.

From class page1 to page2.
On page1:

```
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(page1.this, page2.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("key", 1); //Your id
            intent.putExtras(b); //Put your id to your next Intent
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

On page2: I am writing this code in onCreate function.

```
    Bundle coming = getIntent().getExtras();
    int value = coming.getInt("key");
    paper.setText(value);
```

Comment: Not 100% but could it be your `paper` `TextView` is not initialised yet? Is it a `NullPointerException` you're getting?

Comment: if emulator is not working its not meaning that problem is in code. you should check logcat for more info.

Comment: You should look into logcat and tell what actual problem you are facing. Like if any exception is being thrown.

Answer (score 2):

You have to **cast** `int` to `String` as you are trying to set it to `TextView`

So change:

```
paper.setText(value);
```

to:

```
paper.setText(String.valueOf(value));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a text value to your TextView

```
Bundle coming = getIntent().getExtras();
int value = coming.getInt("key");
// Add an empty string to value
paper.setText(value + "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Before setText convert value int to String

```
paper.setText(String.valueOf(value));
```

Answer (score -1):

There are few ways to do it, It is depend on your requirement. I'll show how it can be done,

1. If you want to pass single parameter it is better to pass it with the intent like follow.

`b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), page2.class);
        intent.putExtra("key", 1); //Your id
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});`

and you can receive data back in page2 Activity as

```
int id = getIntent().getIntExtra("key",1);
```

2. Can use bundle for pass bundle of data

   `b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), page2.class);
       //Create the bundle
       Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
       //Add your data from getFactualResults method to bundle
       bundle.putString("key", 1);
       //Add the bundle to the intent
       intent.putExtras(bundle);
       startActivity(intent);
   }
   });`

receive data from page2 Activity

`Bundle bundle = null;
bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String keyString = bundle.getString("Name");//this is for String`

3. Add data to the sharedPreferences and retrieve it from page2 Activity

`SharedPreferences sp =getSharedPreferences(logFile, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putString("id", 1);
    editor.commit();`

And can retrive it from next page